# How to declare global variable using Set-Variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, global-variables

Consider the below code:

```
Set-Variable -Name session -Value $null -Scope Global

function Manage-SecondAdmin {
    Close-Session
    $session = Open-Session
}

$session = Open-Session
Manage-SecondAdmin
$x = Invoke-Session $session
# Outputs success string or nothing in case of failure
if ($x) {
    # Does not come here
    Write-Host "Success"
} else {
    # Comes here
    Write-Host "Invalid session ID"
    $session = Open-Session
}
$x = Invoke-Session $session
# Now successful response
```

When I use the above code, it always go to else part as explained in the command. I am aware of the keyword 'global'. Is it needed when I use 'Set-Variable'? What is the best approach for this?

Comment: @AdminOfThings, Updated the question with comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$session` in `Manage-SecondAdmin` is a different variable than `$global:session`. Apparently `Close-Session` (whatever that cmdlet might be) closes the existing session, and the subsequent `Open-Session` opens a new one, which is then assigned it to the *local* variable `$session` in the scope of the function while the *global* variable `$session` still holds the reference to the now closed session. You could probably fix that by changing `$session` to `$global:session`, but manipulating global variables in nested contexts is a bad practice. Don't do that.

Have the function return the new session and assign the return value to a variable where the function is called:

```
function Manage-SecondAdmin {
    Close-Session
    Open-Session
}

$session = Open-Session
$session = Manage-SecondAdmin
...
```

Pre-defining your variables with `Set-Variable` normally isn't required in PowerShell.